# Why does BuiltinImporter.create_module only restore part of the builtins module?

Tags: python, python-import, built-in, cpython

I was doing a challenge to prove that `eval` and `exec` are dangerous even if they don't have access to any builtins. The challenge goes like this:

```
vars(__builtins__).clear()
del __builtins__

...  # your code here

print('you win')  # if this line doesn't crash, you win
```

I came up with some crazy code that gains access to the mutilated `builtins` module and re-imports it in order to restore its functionality. This is the code I used to pass the challenge (tested in CPython 3.7):

```
type = ''.__class__.__class__
ABCMeta = type.__subclasses__(type)[0]
abc_globals = ABCMeta.register.__globals__
importlib_globals = abc_globals['__loader__'].get_data.__globals__
sys = importlib_globals['sys']
__builtins__ = sys.modules['builtins']
loader = sys.modules['_frozen_importlib'].BuiltinImporter
spec = sys.modules['_frozen_importlib'].ModuleSpec('builtins', loader)
loader.create_module(spec)
loader.exec_module(__builtins__)
__builtins__.__spec__ = spec
```

But after passing the challenge, I noticed that some builtin functions and classes were still missing:

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'exit' is not defined
>>> KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'KeyError' is not defined
```

Why is this? Why did `BuiltinImporter.create_module(...)` restore `int` and `print`, but not `exit` and `KeyError`?

Comment: Exit is not an actual builtin

Comment: https://ideone.com/Zn18o9

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure how `type.__module__` is relevant here? It's `builtins`, as expected.

Comment: Isn't that a much simpler way to get a reference to it? Sorry, totally unrelated to your question. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, the `__module__` attribute only stores the *name* of the module, not the module object itself :(

Comment: Oh. That explains a lot. That's what I get for not reading.

Comment: `exit` is added to the built-in namespace by the `site` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit